# Access denied while fetching contents in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell ,trying to load file contents using
$contet =Get-Content -Path "c:\data\abc.txt"
this is working fine
but when i am trying to fetch contents from one drive
$contents = Get-Content -Path :"C:\Users\Onedrivabc.txt"
it is throwing get-content: Access to this path is deneied
how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

In order to write directly to the C:/ directory you have to have admin privileges. So either run powershell as an admin or you can open an admin window from your standard window.

Starting PowerShell with administrative privileges from a regular, non-elevated Command Prompt window is a pretty roundabout way of doing things. You actually need to invoke PowerShell from Command Prompt to launch a different PowerShell window.

To do so, type or paste powershell start-process `powershell -verb runas` into Powershell, and then hit Enter. A new elevated PowerShell window will appear.